# Cosa significa "smanacciato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Fu sul punto di mostrarmi anche i conti che aveva buttato giù, di nascosto da Rino, per capire quanto denaro serviva veramente per realizzarle. Poi si fermò, ripiegò i fogli **smanacciati** e mi disse che era inutile perdere tempo: suo padre aveva ragione.

Ho cercato il significato di "smanacciare" in alcuni dizionari. Tuttavia non capisco cosa intendi l'autrice per "fogli smanacciati" nel passaggio sopra citato. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Forse è simile il castigliano *manoseado*.

Comment: @DaG: Penso che tu abbia ragione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Smanacciare](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=smanacciare):

> - manipolare qualcosa maldestramente: *smanacciare il pc.* (Garzanti)

Penso si riferisca a fogli che erano stati manipolati senza cura, sgualciti.